# SOAP UI Error when trying to load wsdl

Tags: soapui

I am getting the following error when I try to access the Web Service

[image]

Comment: It is clear from the error that there seemed to have an issue with wsdl. It is really difficult for other to resolve. You need to have the wsdl fixed. Please report it to the wsdl provider.

Comment: Also, try opening the `wsdl` in the browser and see if that works.

Comment: @Rao Yes the wsdl opens up correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Soap UI 5.2.0

The solution for me was to turn off the proxy

[image: SoapUI example]